# GIO example for opening a server port?

Tags: gtk

Can you please tell me if there is any example for using GIO Server Socket
(the one which I can open a port and listen on socket requests)?
I would like to use it to 'remote-control' my GTK+ application.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do something like this:

```
#define MY_PORT 47110

/* Listener callback, this gets called by GTK+ when
 * there's socket activity to handle.
*/
static gboolean cb_listener(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data
{
  switch(condition)
  {
  case G_IO_IN:
    /* There's data to be read. */
    break;
  default:
    /* An error has occured, or socket is closed. */
    return FALSE; /* This tells GIO to remove the source, might be drastic. */
  }
  return TRUE; /* This tells GIO that all is fine. */
}
```

Then elsewhere (in a function, maybe `main()`):

```
GSocketListener *listener;

listener = g_socket_listener_new();
g_socket_listener_add_inet_port(listener, MY_PORT, NULL, NULL);
g_io_add_watch(G_IO_CHANNEL(listener), G_IO_IN | G_IO_ERR | G_IO_HUP, cb_listener, NULL);
```