# How do I receive UDP broadcast packets using GTK / GIO?

Tags: udp, gtk, listener, broadcast, gio

I have a custom product (running Linux) spitting out broadcast packets every few seconds to port 38280.

Here's a screen capture of Wireshark showing the packets in question.

[image: Wireshark capture]

Under a Linux VM (Ubuntu 22.04 guest, Win11 host), I can run netcat to see these broadcast packets:-

```
$ nc -lu 38280
<xmllink><hello address="0" id="C8A0308399A3" ident="13579"/></xmllink>
```

I'm now trying to write a simple GTK app to listen out for these packets.

So far, I have tried using `g_socket_listener_add_inet_port()` but (after some extra testing) this will only see the packets if I send the packets directly to the IP address & port (rather than a broadcast message).

```
g_socket_listener_add_inet_port((GSocketListener*)l_svcKnockKnock, l_nSlaveAnnouncePort, NULL, &error);
```

Can anyone explain what I'm missing ?

Is `g_socket_listener_add_inet_port()` only for TCP packets ?

If so, how can I setup a listener for UDP broadcasts ?

**UPDATE**

I've now found [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012061/glib-gio-asynchronous-or-threaded-udp-server) which gave me some working code.

Note that it doesn't use a normal listener service ... instead it adds a watch to the socket using `g_io_add_watch()`.

Not sure how portable this is but it works for me !!

Answer (score 0):

> Is g_socket_listener_add_inet_port() only for TCP packets ?

Yes.

You should be able to handle UDP with the slightly lower level `g_socket_listener_add_address()`.

Comment: I did try that but kept on getting "operation not supported".

I guess I had an incorrect parameter but couldn't find any examples to refer to.