# AIX 7.2 GLib-GObject signal incoming is invalid

Tags: c, tcp, aix, glib, gio

I have problem with glib2.56.1-2 from Linux toolbox. I have simple TCP server example I have found:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GError * error = NULL;

  /* create the new socketservice */
  GSocketService* service = g_socket_service_new ();

  /* connect to the port */
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  memset(&serv_addr, 0x0, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8000);

  g_socket_listener_add_address ((GSocketListener*)service,
    g_socket_address_new_from_native(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)),
                                     G_SOCKET_TYPE_STREAM,
                                     G_SOCKET_PROTOCOL_TCP,
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     &error);

  /* listen to the 'incoming' signal */
  g_signal_connect (service,
                "incoming",
                G_CALLBACK (incoming_callback),
                NULL);

  /* start the socket service */
  g_socket_service_start (service);

  /* enter mainloop */
  g_print ("Waiting for client!\n");
  GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
  g_main_loop_run(loop);

  return 0;
}
```

But it gives me following warning:

```
(process:9633862): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:48:11.025: gsignal.c:2523: signal 'incoming' is invalid for instance '110015730' of type 'GSocketService'
```

Connection seems to be opended, but it is not possible to handle incoming data due to signal warning you see above. Do you have any idea?

Regards, Jiri.

Comment: If you run under `valgrind`, is there any memory corruption?

Comment: I found another question. I cannot see any significant difference (at the first glance) but you may yourself have a look at it: [SO: GIO socket-server / -client example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10085464/7478597).

Comment: Please edit your post: add the `#include` lines and the command you use to create the executable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. When I removed -Wl,-G from linker flags, it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed -Wl,-G from linker flags. That worked fine. Thank you all.